# Sql range query

Tags: sql, oracle

Query returning 2 values from table `TBL_CHARGES`:

```
Range_in_hrs    Range_to_hours   charges
       4             48            5
      48             70           10
      70             90           20
```

Select charges from table if range 47.59 is passed the return charge should be 5. If 48.00 is passed the charges will be 5.
If 48.01 is passed the charges should be 10.

I am trying this

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL_CHARGES
WHERE 48.00 between Range_in_hrs and Range_to_hours
```

But it does not works.

Comment: Data types for Range_in_hrs and Range_to_hours columns?

Comment: Data type for both the column is  number

Comment: which database? You have to cast your 48:00  /  47:49 etc. AND the data in the columns Range_to_hours and Range_to_hrs to datetime-values in order to compare them.

Comment: what datatype do you think `48:00` is?

Comment: @FlorinGhita 48.0 is getting from two column 48 and 0 which is appended by . both are number

Comment: @DavidHermanns it is not decimal ... value is from two colum 48 and 00 which is concatenate by .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem got solved by this query.

SELECT * 
FROM TBL_CHARGES
WHERE 48.00 between Range_in_hrs||'.01'  and Range_to_hours||'.00'

Comment: Which will fail if the value is 48.001.

Comment: actually it is minutes stored in the table no chance of 001 as the value lie between 00 to 59

Comment: still, it would be better to use explicit ranges than to mimic them using between and some data-tweaking, imho.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to avoid using `BETWEEN` and instead use explicit ranges, like so:

```
select * 
from   tbl_charges
where  48 > range_in_hrs
and    48 <= range_to_hours;
```

And here's an example that shows the output you might get with various different values:

```
with tbl_charges as (select 4 range_in_hours, 48 range_to_hours, 5 charges from dual union all
                     select 48 range_in_hours, 70 range_to_hours, 10 charges from dual union all
                     select 70 range_in_hours, 90 range_to_hours, 20 charges from dual),
            vals as (select 4 val from dual union all
                     select 4.01 val from dual union all
                     select 47.59 val from dual union all
                     select 48 val from dual union all
                     select 48.01 val from dual union all
                     select 70 val from dual union all
                     select 71 val from dual)
select vals.val,
       tc.charges
from   vals
       left outer join tbl_charges tc on (vals.val > tc.range_in_hours and vals.val <= tc.range_to_hours);

       VAL    CHARGES
---------- ----------
         4           
      4.01          5
     47.59          5
        48          5
     48.01         10
        70         10
        71         20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT charges 
FROM TBL_CHARGES
WHERE ceil(to_number('48.01')) between Range_in_hrs and Range_to_hours
```

Use Replace and Ceil.